# Failed to launch application "WcfTestClient.exe"

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-4, wcftestclient

when i add more than 38 service and try to run my WCF project from visual studio. It gives following Error.

[image]

Failed to launch application "WcfTestClient.exe"

After clicking on yes it stop. and after clicking on no it show itself in running mode but I am not able to see Wcf Test Client. and not able to invoke service.

with 38 services in app.config it works properly.

My app.config looks as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Operation">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IOperation" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/BusinessLogic/Operation" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.UserService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IUserService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9002/BusinessLogic/UserService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.UserCreationService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IUserCreationService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9003/BusinessLogic/UserCreationService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Modules">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IModule" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9004/BusinessLogic/Modules" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Menu">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IMenu" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9005/BusinessLogic/Menu" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Role">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IRole" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9006/BusinessLogic/Role" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.EmailConfiguration">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IEmailConfiguration" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9007/BusinessLogic/EmailConfiguration" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.SmsConfiguration">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.ISmsConfiguration" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9008/BusinessLogic/SmsConfiguration" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Country">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.ICountry" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9009/BusinessLogic/Country" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.State">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IState" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9010/BusinessLogic/State" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.SystemAdminConfigurations">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.ISystemAdminConfiguration" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9011/BusinessLogic/SystemAdminConfigurations" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Salutation">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.ISalutation" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9012/BusinessLogic/Salutation" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.City">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.ICity" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9013/BusinessLogic/City" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.BusinessUnit">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IBusinessUnit" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9014/BusinessLogic/BusinessUnit" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.QualificationStreams">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IQualificationStream" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9015/BusinessLogic/QualificationStreams" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.CommunicationType">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.ICommunicationType" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9016/BusinessLogic/CommunicationType" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.IndustryType">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IIndustryType" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9017/BusinessLogic/IndustryType" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Designation">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IDesignation" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9018/BusinessLogic/Designation" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.QualificationType">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IQualificationType" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9019/BusinessLogic/QualificationType" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.IndustrySubTypes">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IIndustrySubTypes" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9020/BusinessLogic/IndustrySubTypes" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Qualification">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IQualification" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9021/BusinessLogic/Qualification" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SalesDb.WorkOrderCategory">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SalesDb.IWorkOrderCategory" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9022/BusinessLogic/WorkOrderCategory" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.UsersRole">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IUsersRole" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9023/BusinessLogic/UsersRole" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Company">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.ICompany" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9024/BusinessLogic/Company" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Audit">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IAudit" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9025/BusinessLogic/Audit" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.GeneralConfigurations">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IGeneralConfiguration" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9026/BusinessLogic/GeneralConfigurations" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.AuditPurging">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IAuditPurging" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9027/BusinessLogic/AuditPurging" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.NoLogging">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.INoLogging" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9028/BusinessLogic/NoLogging" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.Notification">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.INotification" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9029/BusinessLogic/Notification" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SysAdmin.EmailNotification">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SysAdmin.IEmailNotification" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9030/BusinessLogic/EmailNotification" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SalesDb.VerificationStatus">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SalesDb.IVerificationStatus" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9104/BusinessLogic/VerificationStatus" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SalesDb.Sources">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SalesDb.ISources" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9101/BusinessLogic/Sources" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>


      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SalesDb.Courses">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SalesDb.ICourse" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9102/BusinessLogic/Courses" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SalesDb.SubSource">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SalesDb.ISubSources" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9103/BusinessLogic/SubSource" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SalesDb.Batches">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SalesDb.IBatch" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9105/BusinessLogic/Batches" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>


      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.BusinessLogic.SalesDb.SMSTemplates">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPBindingConfig"
          name="TCPEndpoint" contract="QuexstERP.BusinessCore.Interfaces.SalesDb.ISmsTemplate" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="TcpMetaData" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9106/BusinessLogic/SMSTemplates" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>



    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TCPBindingConfig" maxBufferSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="21" maxConcurrentSessions="50" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

38 services, really ? WcfTestClient  internally uses svcutil to generate proxy code. 38 is maybe too much.

Hopefully, WCfTestClient can be launch without Visual Studio.

You can find the WCF Test Client (WcfTestClient.exe) in the following location: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio XX\Common7\IDE\`. It depends on VS version.

Because you are exposing mex endpoint, you can easily add a net.tcp service url such as `net.tcp://localhost:9106/BusinessLogic/SMSTemplates/mex` (url to be confirmed)